# Phonegap plugin error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I`m trying to build a flashlight app, but it did not work on my device, in Firebug I have strange error:

```
ReferenceError: cordova is not defined 
cordova.addConstructor(Flashlight.install);
```

I use https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/294 plugin

My code index.html

```
<div id="button2" class="button1">Click!</div>
```

My code flashlightexec.js

```
$("#button2").live('click', function(){
    window.plugins.flashlight.available(function(isAvailable) {
      if (isAvailable) {

        window.plugins.flashlight.switchOn();
        alert("ok");

      } else {
        alert("Flashlight not available on this device");
      }
    });
});
```

Plugin code:

```
function Flashlight() {
  // track flashlight state
  this._isSwitchedOn = false;
}

Flashlight.prototype = {

  available: function (callback) {
    cordova.exec(function (avail) {
      callback(avail ? true : false);
    }, null, "Flashlight", "available", []);
  },

  switchOn: function (successCallback, errorCallback) {
    this._isSwitchedOn = true;
    cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "Flashlight", "switchOn", []);
  },

  switchOff: function (successCallback, errorCallback) {
    this._isSwitchedOn = false;
    cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "Flashlight", "switchOff", []);
  },

  toggle: function (successCallback, errorCallback) {
    if (this._isSwitchedOn) {
      this.switchOff(successCallback, errorCallback);
    } else {
      this.switchOn(successCallback, errorCallback);
    }
  }
};

Flashlight.install = function () {
  if (!window.plugins) {
    window.plugins = {};
  }

  window.plugins.flashlight = new Flashlight();
  return window.plugins.flashlight;
};

cordova.addConstructor(Flashlight.install);
```

What should I change to make flashlight works? Maybe there is another solution&

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add the reference to cordova.js in your index.html before including the plugin .js file. Also, wait for the deviceready event to fire.

Comment: Hey Eddy, I am using phoneGap Build to make flashlight app using same plugin. but no luck can you please help me out. Have same problem. I include Phonegap.js in script, also Flashlight.js and java file also in src folder.

Comment: Note that currently the Phonegap Build 1.1 version of this plugin has a bug; the isAvailable function always returns false on Android, I hope a newer version gets approved quickly. In the meantime use the 1.0 version or omit the isAvailable check.